# Merging 2 partial torrent downloads into one

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

The reason why I ended up with this is hard to explain but basically, I have the same 400gb torrent, which was partially downloaded at about 40%, twice:

/FolderA/400gb torrent at 40%

/FolderB/400gb torrent at 40%

Now, if I could merge both folders together, I would probably have 60% of the torrent downloaded, saving a few Gb in download.

Is there a way to merge them ? So that I don't have to resume one of the 2 downloads and loose the data gathered from the other one ?

Comment: Run 2 independent utorrent, and let them synchronize the data via LPD.

Comment: Could you point me towards a tutorial or something ? Will it be efficient (not using bandwidth, given both downloads folders are on the same hard drive ? (Feel free to respond as an answer so I can mark it as such)

Comment: I've never tried it, so this is only a tip. Disable the outgoing network interface, and wait for the 2 utorrents see each other, then they will trade bytes.

Comment: Ok, well this mean I got to "check" the old torrent, which will take 3 days alone. Sooo... I guess I'll let you know how it went in 3 days. (ridiculous how long it take to check a torrent... considering windows force-rebooted for update installing an hour after I had finally re-checked it already. It's checking the exact same data again...)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with torram (https://github.com/vbuell/torram). It merges content of multiple download directories into one. So based that directories are:

/MyDownloads/FolderA
/MyDownloads/FolderB

you can use:

```
torram -c -o <output_directory> <yourtorrentfile.torrent> /MyDownloads
```